Rings of holomorphic functions (of one complex variable) is a Bezout's domain
I am trying to solve the following problem:

Show that if $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, every finitely generated ideal of $H(U)$ is a principal ideal.

I know that if $\{g_1,\cdots,g_n\}$ is a set of generators of some ideal $I$ of $H(U)$ such that $g_i$ has no common zero, then $I$ is trivial for the equation $f_1g_1+\cdots+f_ng_n=1$ holds for some $f_i\in H(U)$. Therefore it suffices to consider the case that there exists at least one common zero, say $\lambda\in U$, such that $g_i(\lambda)=0$ for all $i$.
The case may be reduced to two generators, therefore we may consider the case $I=\left<f\right>+\left<g\right>$, where $f,g\in H(U)$ and $f,g$ share at least one common zero. I need to show there exists some $h\in H(U)$ such that $\left<f\right>+\left<g\right>=\left<h\right>$, however I can't see how to do this.

Suppose WLOG that $0 \in U$, that the zero is at $0$, and that the orders of the zero for $f$ and $g$ respectively are $a$ and $b$. What happens if you try to divide by $z^{\text{min}(a, b)}$?
